# Is there a way to set subtext in Bot Framework enum options?

Tags: c#, enums, botframework

```
public enum PlanOptions
{
    [Description("Adult (USD 15 each) 18 – 65 years old")]
    Adult = 1,

    [Description("Child (USD 60 each ) 0 – 17 years old")]
    Child = 2,

    [Description("Family (USD 120 for the whole family) *Maximum of 2 parents and 3 children per plan.")]
    Family = 3,
};
```

I want "18 - 65 years old", "0 - 17 years old", "*Maximum of 2 parents and 3 children per plan." to appear as subtexts
[image: I want it to look like this]

Comment: The short answer is no.

Comment: @JasonSowers Is there a long answer where I can cram the text I need into the list of options?

Comment: Not using an Enum, the long answer I was thinking of is you may be able to pull something off using [adaptive cards](http://adaptivecards.io)

Comment: I am familiar with those... I know how to use adaptive cards outside of the Form Dialog. Can you point me to a sample where they use cards in a Form? In the form builder I always use .Field(nameof(FirstName),
                    active: (state) =>
                    {
                        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(state.FirstName);
                    }) and can't figure out how to use cards in there...

Comment: @JasonSowers I am actually only aware of HeroCards, I will look into adaptive cards as you pointed out. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: This is probably not possible in a form. I'm not 100% sure of that though